# Make lists from existing Main list

Tags: python, list, split

I have a main list from which I need to create 3 separate lists. The first 5 values of the main list remain stable and could be used for `firs_list`, and the last 5 also could be used for the `third_list`. The problem is that the second list that is in between could be one value or more like in "Estats Units d'Amèrica" or one value like  "Mexic"

```
main_list = ['15 de Març del 1997 Mèxic 03 de Gener del 2023', '08 de Octubre del 1988 Suècia 09 de Febrer del 2023', '08 de Desembre del 1991 Estats Units d'Amèrica 09 de Febrer del 2023']
```

Desired result for 3 lists:

```
first_list = ['15 de Març del 1997', '08 de Octubre del 1988','08 de Desembre del 1991']
segond_list = ['Mèxic','Suècia','Estats Units d'Amèrica']
third_list = ['03 de Gener del 2023','09 de Febrer del 2023','09 de Febrer del 2023']
```

I tried with split some combinations like this one with no success.

```
first_list = [item.split(' ', 6)[6] for item in main_list]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  There is an issue with your use of ```'Estats Units d'Amèrica'```.   You need to either use ```"``` or escape the ```'``` in ```d'Amèrica'```

Answer (score 0):

Since the list is not well formed, please try the options mentioned in the comment by @ewokx. After reforming the list, the below answer would help. In my case, I have escaped the ' in 'America by adding a "\" before 'America

```
main_list = ['15 de Març del 1997 Mèxic 03 de Gener del 2023', '08 de Octubre del 1988 Suècia 09 de Febrer del 2023', '08 de Desembre del 1991 Estats Units d\'Amèrica 09 de Febrer del 2023']
first_list = []
second_list = []
third_list = []
for i in main_list:
    temp = i.split(" ")
    first_list.append(" ".join(temp[:5]))
    second_list.append(temp[5])
    third_list.append(" ".join(temp[6:]))
print(first_list)
print(second_list)
print(third_list)
```